# Detalized pricing for google cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

Where I can get a detailed price for what I did spend?  In google cloud console https://prnt.sc/117bsnx  I see only  the sum for the entire project but didn't see details

Comment: Will the [billing report](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports) help?

Answer (score 0):

As [@berndbausch](https://serverfault.com/users/380923/berndbausch) suggested, to view your billing reports and cost trends you can address to the [Cloud Billing Reports](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports) page.